# Add NEW data to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

So I have a CSV with 3 columns: VM, GB, Timestamp.

What I am attempting to do is:

If the file does not exist make a new CSV from the dataset `$VMdata`. Else UPDATE the CSV with data from `$VMdata` that is not in `$csv` already (NEW data since `$VMdata` will have a bunch of old data too).

I have attempted to use the following code:

```
if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($csv)) {
    $VMdata | Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation
} else {
    $importvmstat = Import-Csv $VMdata

    $newvmstat = $importvmstat + $VMstattest | Select Unique
    $newvmstat | Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Unfortunately for some reason `$newvmstat = $importvmstat + $VMstattest` doesn't  work the way I want to and `$newvmstat` only includes data from one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a single command for both scenarios, just use `-Append` with `Export-Csv`:

```
$VMdata |  Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

If the file exists it will add the `$VMData` to the file, if not a new file will be created.

---

Import the existing csv and add the new data to it, then select only the unique entries:

```
$FullData = (Import-Csv -Path $csv) + $VMdata | Select -Unique VM,GB,Timestamp

$FullData | Out-GridView

$FullData | Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks ...I thought about that, but it adds data that already exists, so I end up having duplicates. The other problem is before sending to csv I want to load it on a variable to easily `Out-Gridview`

Comment: Holy crap... Thanks... I realized what I was doing wrong.... forgetting to select the members after select unique ...as shown above... so simple, easy and obvious .... i feel like a freakin dumbass lol ....